# How to insert a key/value pair into a dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

When I add an entry to a `Dictionary` using `Add`, the `KeyValuePair` is added at the end of it. I would like to preppend it thus when I iterate on `KeyValuePair`'s, it is the first item.

Is there a way to do it with a `Dictionary` or should I build a `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` or do you have a better proposition?

**EDIT :** I thought I could work on the enumeration in `Dictionary`, it seems I can't.

I tried with `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` which was not very practical.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Dictionary` class doesn't have a concept of order within it - there is no positional index to the `Dictionary`.

Take a look at the [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary) class in the `System.Collections.Specialized` namespace if you need to use a positional index on a dictionary.

Comment: You are speaking of the positional index; however, there is a indexer based on the key.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - Thanks you for your comment. Clarified answer.

Comment: Is there a generic version of `OrderedDictionary`? What I ask for is a type-safe (generic) dictionary where the key-value pairs are ordered like a `List<>` (**not** sorted by the key).

Comment: Great ! that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - Yes, there is (updated answer with link).

Comment: No, sorry, wrong update by you. The link is to a generic dictionary that is sorted by key. So if you say first `dict.Add("Beta", 10);` then `dict.Add("Alpha", 10);`, then the items will come in the order of the keys (`"Alpha"` is collated before `"Beta"`), **not** in the order of addition to the dictionary (`"Beta"` was added before `"Alpha"`). Maybe the authors of .NET decided that an ordered dictionary performs too poorly?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - You are right. There doesn't seem to be an ordered generic dictionary built in.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for the [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Use `OrderedDictionary`.

Represents a collection of key/value pairs that are accessible by the key or index. You can insert the key value pait at desired index.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to preserve order, `Dictionary` is not the collection that you want to use (it doesn't have a concept of order).

There is an [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) collection that will help if you need to have an indexed dictionary.

There is also a [`SortedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) collection, that will sort the values that you add based on the key value.

Answer (score 0):

Officially, you can never know in what order your key-value pairs will come out of a `Dictionary<,>` if you iterate through it (`foreach` it, thereby calling `GetEnumerator()`). And certainly, if you `Remove` some items from your dictionary, and later `Add` some other items, when you `foreach` your way through the collection, the new items will be in the space of the removed items, **not** in the end of the iteration "list".

But: If you know you never `Delete` from your `Dictionary<,>`, it looks like the enumeration yields the items in the order they were added. There is no guarantee this will always work, but it looks like it works in the current implementation.

So **if** you dare rely on this, you could just say

```
foreach (var keyValuePair in myDict.Reverse())
{
  ...
```

The `Reverse` method is part of LINQ (needs `using System.Linq`).